# preg_match($username, '/\W/') (or, yet another "preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash")

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've looked at the (many) other similar posts, and they're just not doing it for me.

I'm trying to confirm that $username contains only "word" characters -- alphanumerics and/or underscores.  My code is:

```
if (preg_match($username, '/\W/')) {
    //stuff happens
}
```

and I'm getting the "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash" message.  I'm sure it's something blindingly obvious, but can someone see what I'm doing wrong?  I've experimented with single/double quotes and doubling the backspace, but nothing works.  Thanks!

Comment: You got your parameters to `preg_match` backwards.

Comment: "I'm sure it's something blindingly obvious" - You are correct, sir. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, you have your [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) parameters the wrong way round. Also, you may wish to look at the [ctype_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php) family of functions.

Oh, and I think you're after `\w`, not `\W` see [this too](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Comment: (actually, given the situation of the call, \W is correct  But thanks in any case.)